# How to document a type of the variable that can be an object of any kind that implements an interface in Python?

Tags: python, interface, python-sphinx, docstring

I have a code of the following structure:

An interface `ISomething` (i.e. a base abstract class):

```
class ISomething:
    # some methods that should be implemented in classes
    # that implement this interface
```

Various classes that implement an `ISomething` interface:

```
class SomethingA(ISomething):
    # implementation of the interface

class SomethingB(ISomething):
    # implementation of the interface
(...)
class SomethingZ(ISomething):
    # implementation of the interface
```

My other class requires an object of the one of the classes `SomethingA`, `SomethingB`, ..., `SomethingZ` in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, something):
    '''
    Constructor

    :param something: Param description
    :type something: *Anything that implements ISomething interface*
    '''

    self._something = something
```

As you can see I use `Sphing Docstring`. However, I'm looking for the general answer.

My questing is: how to document that a variable is an object of any class that implements ISomething interface.

Currently, I documented the type of this variable to be "one from the list", i.e.:

```
:type something: SomethingA|SomethingB|...|SomethingZ
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I feel that it would be better to keep it more general.

Comment: What do you mean by "general answer"? Why isn't "Anything that implements ISomething interface" good enough?

Comment: I would prefer some kind of notation. Of course, I'm not sure if such notation exists.

Comment: By "notation" I mean something shorter. In addition, I'm looking for something used by others - if such thing exists :)

Comment: @Marein: It would have to be `:type something: ISomething`.

Comment: Since in Python an 'interface' is just a class which other classes subclass, wouldn't it suffice to just say :type something: ISomething? (thanks @mzjn for the correction)

Comment: @Marein Is it possible for you to create an answer from your comment? I'd like to be able to grant the bounty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in Python an 'interface' is simply a class which other classes subclass, it might suffice to just say `:type something: ISomething`.

In full:

```
class ISomething:
    # some methods that should be implemented in classes
    # that implement this interface

class SomethingA(ISomething):
    # implementation of the interface

class SomethingB(ISomething):
    # implementation of the interface

class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self, something):
        '''
        Constructor

        :param something: Param description
        :type something: ISomething
        '''

       self._something = something
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a :precondition:

:precondition: isinstance(something, ISomething)